# Refresh the directory Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find whether a file is downloaded or not. It takes time to get downloaded. meanwhile I want refresh the downloads directory for every 10 secs. code:

```
    flag=1
    while flag :
         print("10 secs...")
         time.sleep(10)
         for file in files:
              if (some condition):
                  print("found"+file)
                  flag =0
```

Comment: Alright... What's the question?! You have a task, you have some code, and questions usually end with a question mark...

Comment: How are you doing the downloading? With the subprocess module? If so it'll automatically wait for the command to finish.

Comment: I'm downloading the file using selenium. In order to go further step I need to check whether file got download. I can see the file has downloaded. But my code unable to trace the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your own wait loop, try the [Watchdog](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/) package.

From the docs: "*A cross-platform Python API library and shell utilities to monitor file system events.*"